# Recursive removal of characters in Java

Tags: java, methods, recursion, character

As an exercise, the code block below intends to recursively go through a string and remove all the of the "x" characters. It does that, but I would like to keep track of the newStr without passing it as a parameter in the method. Is there anyway to move it into the method body?

Thanks!

```
public static String deathToX(String str, String newStr) {  
    //look for x char
    if(str.substring(0, 1).equals("x")) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        //add non-x char to newStr
        newStr += str.charAt(0);
    }

    if(str.length() == 1) {
        return newStr;
    }

    return deathToX(str.substring(1), newStr);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Return: " + deathToX("xnoxmore", ""));
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  There are many easier and more efficient ways to do this, if you're not constrained in your approach to the problem.

Comment: No, not homework. I'm just trying to practice writing recursive methods, so the restrictions are self-imposed. Although I am aware that this is a much easier problem to solve if I were not tied to writing it as a recursive method.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you could change the code to:

```
public static String deathToX(String str)
{   
    // Termination case
    if (str.length() == 0)
    {
        return str;
    }
    // Work out whether or not we want the first character
    String prefix = str.startsWith("x") ? "" : str.substring(0, 1);

    // Let the recursive call handle the rest of the string, and return
    // the prefix (empty string or the first character) followed by the
    // x-stripped remainder.
    return prefix + deathToX(str.substring(1));
}
```

Is that the sort of thing you were thinking of?

Of course, this is a horribly inefficient way of doing string manipulation, but I assume you're more interested in the recursive nature of things.

Comment: I'm not sure `newStr` is being used at all, in this new version.

Comment: I was going to edit your solution, but then I saw that someone else had done that change, and you had added `newStr` back in a second edit...so I decided to leave it up to you.  I wasn't positive how that social protocol works here on SO...

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I suspect it was just a matter of edits crossing, to be honest, while I was adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to keep track of the newStr without passing it as a parameter in the method.

Why? Passing the intermediary result into the function is often required in functional-style recursive programming. What I do is make a function that handles the bulk of the work and accepts the accumulator, and make a wrapper function that calls the previous one with the required starter value:

```
private static String deathToX0(String str, String newStr) {
    // the original implementation
}

public static String deathToX(String str) {
    return deathToX(str, "");
}
```

As an aside, you might not want to use a `String` for the intermediate result because of the copying involved. A `StringBuilder` would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes... with recursion typically on the way down the tree you work out the bit at each level in this case blank or the current character. So the return statement should call itself recursively then at the bottom of the tree the answer you wanted is reconstructed by adding together the sections at each level.

```
public static String deathToX(String str){
    if (!str.isEmpty()){
        return (str.substring(0, 1).equals("x") ? "" : str.substring(0, 1)) + deathToX(str.substring(1));
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Return: " + deathToX("xnoxmore"));
}
```

In the sample above I used the shorthand if format to put it all on one line but you could expand it out. You should be able to see that the recursive function recurses on the return statement and I put in a special case for the last level. If you were to split it and put this levels answer in a local variable e.g. tmp then you would use:

```
return tmp + deathToX(str.substring(1));
```

Remember recursion means that the current execution is only paused until the lower ones finish so you can happily store info to recover on your way back up. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class solution {

    // Return the changed string
    public static String removeX(String input){
    if(input.equals("") || input.equals("x"))
            return "";

        String returnStr="";
        removeX(input.substring(1));
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
        {
            if(input.charAt(i)=='x')
                continue;
            else
                returnStr+=input.charAt(i);
        }
        return returnStr;
    }
}
```

This is my approach. This code goes to the end of the string, if it gets X as last string, it returns ""(nothing), then it checks the whole substring for "x", if its present in the string, it will continue, else it will append rest character to that string and it goes on.
Finally returns the updated string.!
Hope this helps..!! well, this is my first contribution here :)